# In-plane stresses on the surface of a cylinder

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics, solid-mechanics

The three principal stresses on the surface of a cylinder are the hoop, $\sigma_\theta=\frac{pR}{d}$, longitudinal, $\sigma_z=\frac{pR}{2d}$, and radial, $\sigma_r=-p$, stresses. However, what are the stresses along any direction $\theta$ (w.r.t. $\sigma_\theta$) in the tangential plane at a point $P$, i.e. $\sigma(\theta)$ such that $\sigma(0)=\sigma_\theta$ and $\sigma(\pi/2)=\sigma_z$? If these were curvatures and not stresses, then Euler's theorem of differential geometry would hold: $k(\theta)=k_1\cos^2(\theta)+k_2\sin^2(\theta)$. But I guess it's probably not as simple for mechanical stresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stresses [transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Transformation_rule_of_the_stress_tensor) as $\boldsymbol{\sigma}^\prime=a\boldsymbol{\sigma}a^\text{T}$, where $a$ is the [direction cosine matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine).

Thus, at angle $\theta$ as you've defined it, the (compressive) normal stress you're referring to is

$$\begin{align}\sigma^\prime & =\sigma_\theta\cos^2\theta+\sigma_z\sin^2\theta\\&=\frac{1}{2}(\sigma_\theta+\sigma_z)+\frac{1}{2}(\sigma_\theta-\sigma_z)\cos 2\theta\\&=\frac{pR}{d}\left(\frac{3}{4}+\frac{\cos 2\theta}{4}\right)\end{align}$$

in conjunction with a shear stress with magnitude

$$\begin{align}|\tau^\prime|&=\frac{1}{2}(\sigma_\theta-\sigma_z)\sin 2\theta\\&=\frac{pR}{4d}\sin 2\theta.\end{align}$$

A handy graphical interpretation is [Mohr's circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%27s_circle).

Comment: in the first line of $\sigma'$, should it read $\sigma_\theta\cos^2(\theta)+\sigma_z\sin^2(\theta)$ with a plus instead of a minus?

Comment: Yes, thank you!